# Is it possible to auto increment a property which is not the primary key in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, identity-column

Is it possible to have a primary key and another field which is not the primary key with the "auto increment" function in Entity Framework?

I found this on the web, tried it, but it does not work:

```
public int Id { get; set; }

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ImageId { get; set; }
```

In this case, the Id is always 0.

So now i'm back to this: `Id` is the primary key and i use `MAX(Id) + 1` to increment the `ImageId` integer.

**Update:** I was even thinking of creating another table just for the `ImageId`'s. But i'm not sure it this would be an overkill or not.

Comment: How the schema looks like?

Comment: The MSSQL schema? Now the `Id` is the primary key and the `ImageId` is an integer. I can't figure out how to make the `ImageId` field to auto increment other then `MAX(Id) + 1` which i don't know if it's a good idea.

Comment: MS SQL only allows a single identity column per table.

Comment: @afrazier I know... I just wanted to list what i have already tried so that it wouldn't become an answer as i already know that it can't solve the issue.

Comment: I'd use after insert trigger or make it just a part of the insert/update. Or better - a microservice to keep track of it.

Comment: @abatishchev the trigger sounds good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Tried this sometime ago.   MSSQL does support it. From memory EF didnt allow the definition either.

My solution:
I created a secondary table I called it IDPool. With the sole purpose of generating a unique sequence of ids. I used that value in the main table.  It was a scenario where i could use GUID either. Otherwise Guid is the obvious alternative.

EDIT: Tip  To make things easier/safer, Use a second Context in parallel.
This second context is for getting Ids, You can Commit without fear of  interfering with current update in the main context.

```
      var miniRep = luw.GetRepositoryMini<IdPool>();  // mini context managed here.
      var nextrec = new IdPool()
      miniRep.Add(nextrec);
      miniRep.SaveChanges();
      return nextrec.Id
```

Comment: So far this looks the best solution to me as well... If no one else will come up with a better solution, i will accept your answer as my solution... Will give it a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

Jo Smo,

Try this:

```
public static class ID
{
    // Enumeration for parameter in NewID() method.
    public enum Type { Customer, Vendor, Product, Transaction };
}

public class MyClass
{
    // Variables hold the last ID. This will need to be serialized
    // into your database.
    public int lastCustomerID;
    public int lastVendorID;
    public int lastProductID;
    public int lastTransactionID;

    // Updates last-ID variable and returns its value.
    public int NewID(ID.Type type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case ID.Type.Customer:
                lastCustomerID++;
                return lastCustomerID;

            case ID.Type.Vendor:
                lastVendorID++;
                return lastVendorID;

            case ID.Type.Product:
                lastProductID++;
                return lastProductID;

            case ID.Type.Transaction:
                lastTransactionID++;
                return lastTransactionID;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("An invalid type was passed: " + type);
        }
    }

    private void AnyMethod()
    {
        // Generate new customer ID for new customer.
        int newCustomerID = NewID(ID.Type.Customer);

        // Now the ID is in a variable, and your last-ID variable is updated.
        // Be sure to serialize this data into your database, and deserialize
        // it when creating new instances.
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know if i understood your answer. So you are suggesting to do it all with c#?

Comment: Actually, I just saw your edit. If you can create a table, that's what I would do.